# opencv: writing pixels to image

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have a 48x48 list of piexl values, which I want to write as a grayscale image file.

To do so, I'm converting the list to numpy array and use imwrite.

```
import cv2
from numpy import array
......
#pix is a 48x48 list containing pixel values
pix = array(pix)
cv2.imwrite('test.jpg',pix)
```

However, it returns the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face_detect.py", line 20, in <module>
    cv2.imwrite('test.jpg',pix)
TypeError: img data type = 18 is not supported
```

It obviously has to do with datatype, but what should the second argument of imwrite be if not a numpy array?

Comment: Strange. This piece works `pix = [range(5) for x in xrange(5)]; cv2.imwrite('test.jpg', np.array(pix))`

Comment: @JohnGalt After normalizing the pixel values to 0~1 instead of 0~255, it's working now, but all I'm getting is a black image, regardless of the numbers...

Comment: 0~1 values with respect to 0-255 scale is nothing but 0/1 values, which is black only. Probably, multiply values with 255 and write the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problem, both to the post and my comment below it.

I read the values from a csv file where the numbers were separated by spaces. I used line.split() to break them into separate numbers, but actually I was still treating them as strings.

So all I had to do was to convert them to integers. I didn't need to normalize it either , 0~255 is right.

That was pretty dumb of mine, but in case anybody had the same problem.